# I want to merge two codes but keep giving me an error

Tags: audio, merge, raspberry-pi, record

Hi I am new to python and I am trying to record the sound when there is loudness is over a certain value (in the code 200).

Initially, I had two different pieces of code. one for recording and one for the detecting loudness. I want to merge together and record the sound when the loudness is over 200.

But This keeps giving me an error so I am wondering which part am I missing. 
I would very appreciate if some one help me to figure this out.

```
import time
import grovepi
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'.')
from audio import soundrecord

loudness_sensor = 0

while True:
    try:
        # Read the sound level
        sensor_value = grovepi.analogRead(loudness_sensor)

        print("sensor_value = %d" %sensor_value)
        time.sleep(.5)
        if sensor_value> 200:
            soundrecord()
            time.sleep(10)

    except IOError:
        print ("Error")
```

I defined the below recording code as a soundrecord function and put it in the same directory

```
import pyaudio
import wave

def soundrecord():

    form_1 = pyaudio.paInt16 # 16-bit resolution
    chans = 1 # 1 channel
    samp_rate = 44100 # 44.1kHz sampling rate
    chunk = 4096 # 2^12 samples for buffer
    record_secs = 3 # seconds to record
    dev_index = 2 # device index found by p.get_device_info_by_index(ii)

    wav_output_filename = 'test1.wav' # name of .wav file


    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio() # create pyaudio instantiation

    # create pyaudio stream
    stream = audio.open(format = form_1,rate = samp_rate,channels = chans, \
                        input_device_index = dev_index,input = True, \
                        frames_per_buffer=chunk)
    print("recording")
    frames = []

    # loop through stream and append audio chunks to frame array
    for ii in range(0,int((samp_rate/chunk)*record_secs)):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)

    print("finished recording")

    # stop the stream, close it, and terminate the pyaudio instantiation
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    # save the audio frames as .wav file
    wavefile = wave.open(wav_output_filename,'wb')
    wavefile.setnchannels(chans)
    wavefile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(form_1))
    wavefile.setframerate(samp_rate)
    wavefile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wavefile.close()
```

expecting: Record the sound when the loudness is over 200

actual :

```
sensor_value = 75
sensor_value = 268
Error
sensor_value = 360
Error
sensor_value = 48
sensor_value = 39
sensor_value = 79
```

Comment: The `Error` is happening because that's what you're doing yourself in `except IOError`. What happens if you comment that out and just let the exception occur? What information do you get from the error message then? It does little good to catch the exception and then throw away all of the information it contains and replace it with a meaningless message.

Comment: If i commenct  except IOError: this out than it shows SyntaxError:unexpected E0F while parsing